# SQL - better way to group and sum based on condition

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

I have data like:

| Year | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2001 | 1 |
| 2020 | 2 |
| 2020 | 2 |
| 2021 | 5 |
| 2022 | 2 |
| 2022 | 2 |
| 2021 | 2 |

And I want to summarise data like:

| Year | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 and before | 5 |
| 2021 | 7 |
| 2022 | 4 |

I thought of 2 ways, and want to see whether there are any better method.

1. Use Union

```
Select Year, sum(Amount) from TABLE_A 
where Year <= 2020
UNION
Select Year, sum(Amount) from TABLE_A 
where Year > 2020
```

2. Added a new column

```
SELECT YR, SUM(Amount) FROM
(
  SELECT CASE WHEN Year <= 2020 THEN '2020_and_before') ELSE Year END as YR, * 
  FROM TABLE_A ) A
GROUP BY YR
```

I can get the results I want, but want to see whether there is better method

Comment: I'd go with alternative 2.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (As you have seen now, different products have different ways to do this.)

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can avoid subqueries with a `CASE` expression in the following way:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Year_ <= 2020 THEN "2020 or before"
            ELSE Year_ END AS Year_ ,
       SUM(Amount) AS total_amount
FROM tab       
GROUP BY 1
```

Output:

| Year_ | total_amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 or before | 5 |
| 2021 | 7 |
| 2022 | 4 |

Check a MySQL demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fh6Ate4o6ateiPbacHhTaB/0).

**Note**: You should avoid messing with data types. If you're supposed to store years in the year field, you could leave the integer 2020, instead of having a string like "2020 or before".

Comment: The same for PostgreSQL: https://dbfiddle.uk/OSeNmCBQ  (NOTE: PostgreSQL is less relaxed about the datatypes, than MySQL)   (The `GROUP BY 1` can also be done in PostgreSQL: https://dbfiddle.uk/4YFVM_En )

Comment: Thanks The first link dbfiddle.uk/OSeNmCBQ works for me.